Vorticity vs angular velocity
In fluid mechanics, I got confused by the two terminologies, as both seem mathematically and physically similar.
Vorticity and the angular velocity in the concept of fluid are the measure of the rotationality of the fluid.
Vorticity = 2 * angular velocity = curl of velocity vector

Can you please elaborate on the distinction between the two (both physically and mathematically)? As both are mathematically similar, why are they considered two different terms in fluid texts?
And one more thing: how these two terms are physically different from the circulation of fluid?

Vorticity and the angular velocity in the concept of fluid are the measure of the rotationality of the fluid. I would score this as wrong. Vorticity can be, and very often is, irrotational. In potential flow theory, a vortex source (along with all the other admissible sources, sinks, dipoles, etc.) are irrotational vector or irrotational pseudovector fields. Rotationality describes only the time derivative of a (differential) fluid element's orientation (thus is a vector field). Angular momentum considers the trajectory of the fluid element.

The two are related only when the reference point for the angular momentum calculation is taken as the center of mass of the fluid element. In general that is an accelerating reference frame moving along some trajectory.

Note that mathematical point vortices have a point singularity at their center. So there is a natural reference location for computing angular momentum and assigning a vortex strength to that point.

Concept angular velocity assumes rotation of a solid item around an axis. It, of course can be calculated also for a portion of liquid which is inside say a kettle, the kettle rotates around some axis and the liquid stays in rest relative to the kettle. Moving by having a certain angular velocity around a rotation axis is a very limited special case of all possible motions of fluid. But it has well defined velocity in every point of the fluid and thus can be characterized by using more general concepts. One of them is the curl of the fluid velocity vector field.
Elementary vector field differential- and integral calculus shows that the curl of the velocity vector field of the rotation around an axis is 2 x the angular velocity vector of the rotation.
Hopefully you know how angular velocity vector, rotation axis and the angular rotation speed as radians per second depend on each other and how the angular velocity vector and the place vector of the particle in the rotating medium give the velocity vector if one makes the vector cross product.
Fluid can also have translational motion at the same time when there occurs vortexes. Vorticity is a measure for the rotational part of the combined motion. The formula vorticity = curl of the velocity is the mathematical definition of the term vorticity and it's seen to be useful, because

systematic translation to a certain direction or outwards from a fluid source or towards a fluid sink is totally eliminated by the curl differential operation and
rotation like a solid around a certain axis is in a simple way related to the angular velocity (=multiplier 2)

If you have seen water which flows in a river in a complex way
or a smoker puffing a smoke ring, you surely understand that  the rotational part of the movement can be far more complex than rotating around an axis. But vorticity covers also complex rotations. System designers who desing mechanisms which control fluid movements need the vorticity and ways to predict its density statistically to be able to predict how much there's vortexes which do not actually move the fluid but consume energy and cause pressure.
Elementary vector calculus knowledge including nabla operations and vector field integral theorems by Gauss and Stokes with some physical interpretations are the key part of the understanding fluid mechanics. Without it one cannot handle the basic general equations. Of course, many important special cases can worked out without vector calculus. The same is true also in many other areas. For example one can successfully design electric circuits without knowing the general vector field theory of electromagnetism.
